# VBA Excel - Using Offset in a filtered row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on deleting a row in multiple sheets. I just want to ask if what's wrong with my code? So, before I proceed to the deleting part, I first check if the data that I will delete will be the data that will be selected. So I'm trying to put color first to the result in my filtered table, but unfortunately, it colors the first data in my table and not in the filtered table.

```
Sub del_stud()

    Dim LRN As String, ws As Worksheet
    
    LRN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K11").Value
    
    For Each ws In Sheets(Array("STUDENTS_INFO", "G1-Q1", "G1-Q2"))
    
            With ws.Cells(8, 3)
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=LRN
                '.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
                .Offset(1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End With
   
     Next ws
     
End Sub
```

Here's a visual for my sheet

[image: Picture]